# Failure Exception: ImportError: cannot import name 'HTTPFailure' from 'azure.cosmos.errors' when running function on venv via vscode AZ v4

Tags: azure, function, azure-devops, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb

Im working on upgrading function app from v2 to v4.

Running it locally via venv in vscode.

when running the function

```
func host start --verbose
```

it gives an error: **Result: Failure Exception: ImportError: cannot import name 'HTTPFailure' from 'azure.cosmos.errors'**

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/LATqu.png)

other error message prior to that is here:

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/505wz.png)

**Here are the pip list i have installed:**

```
Package                               Version
------------------------------------- ---------
adal                                  1.2.7    
asn1crypto                            1.5.1    
astroid                               2.15.6   
azure-common                          1.1.28   
azure-core                            1.28.0   
azure-cosmos                          4.4.0    
azure-functions                       1.15.0   
azure-functions-worker                1.1.9    
azure-keyvault                        4.2.0    
azure-keyvault-certificates           4.7.0    
azure-keyvault-keys                   4.8.0    
azure-keyvault-secrets                4.7.0    
azure-mgmt-advisor                    9.0.0    
azure-mgmt-applicationinsights        4.0.0    
azure-mgmt-authorization              4.0.0    
azure-mgmt-batch                      17.1.0   
azure-mgmt-batchai                    2.0.0    
azure-mgmt-billing                    6.0.0    
azure-mgmt-cdn                        12.0.0   
azure-mgmt-cognitiveservices          13.5.0   
azure-mgmt-commerce                   6.0.0    
azure-mgmt-compute                    30.1.0
azure-mgmt-consumption                10.0.0
azure-mgmt-containerinstance          10.1.0
azure-mgmt-containerregistry          10.1.0
azure-mgmt-containerservice           25.0.0
azure-mgmt-core                       1.4.0
azure-mgmt-cosmosdb                   9.2.0
azure-mgmt-datafactory                3.1.0
azure-mgmt-datalake-analytics         0.6.0
azure-mgmt-datalake-nspkg             3.0.1
azure-mgmt-datalake-store             0.5.0
azure-mgmt-datamigration              10.0.0
azure-mgmt-devspaces                  0.2.0
azure-mgmt-devtestlabs                9.0.0
azure-mgmt-dns                        8.1.0
azure-mgmt-eventgrid                  10.2.0
azure-mgmt-eventhub                   11.0.0
azure-mgmt-hanaonazure                1.0.0
azure-mgmt-iotcentral                 9.0.0
azure-mgmt-iothub                     2.4.0
azure-mgmt-iothubprovisioningservices 1.1.0
azure-mgmt-keyvault                   10.2.3
azure-mgmt-loganalytics               12.0.0
azure-mgmt-logic                      10.0.0
azure-mgmt-machinelearningcompute     0.4.1
azure-mgmt-managementgroups           1.0.0
azure-mgmt-managementpartner          1.0.0
azure-mgmt-maps                       2.0.0
azure-mgmt-marketplaceordering        1.1.0
azure-mgmt-media                      10.2.0
azure-mgmt-monitor                    6.0.1
azure-mgmt-msi                        7.0.0
azure-mgmt-network                    24.0.0
azure-mgmt-notificationhubs           8.0.0
azure-mgmt-nspkg                      3.0.2
azure-mgmt-policyinsights             1.0.0
azure-mgmt-powerbiembedded            2.0.0
azure-mgmt-rdbms                      10.1.0
azure-mgmt-recoveryservices           2.4.0
azure-mgmt-recoveryservicesbackup     6.0.0
azure-mgmt-redis                      14.2.0
azure-mgmt-relay                      1.1.0
azure-mgmt-reservations               2.3.0
azure-mgmt-resource                   23.0.1
azure-mgmt-scheduler                  2.0.0
azure-mgmt-search                     9.0.0
azure-mgmt-servicebus                 8.2.0
azure-mgmt-servicefabric              2.0.0
azure-mgmt-signalr                    1.2.0
azure-mgmt-sql                        3.0.1
azure-mgmt-storage                    21.0.0
azure-mgmt-subscription               3.1.1
azure-mgmt-trafficmanager             1.1.0
azure-mgmt-web                        7.1.0
azure-nspkg                           3.0.2
azure-storage-blob                    12.17.0
azure-storage-common                  2.1.0
cachetools                            5.3.1
certifi                               2023.7.22
cffi                                  1.15.1
chardet                               5.1.0
charset-normalizer                    3.2.0
colorama                              0.4.6
coverage                              7.2.7
cryptography                          41.0.2
decorator                             5.1.1
dill                                  0.3.7
exceptiongroup                        1.1.2
grpcio                                1.33.2
grpcio-tools                          1.33.2
idna                                  3.4
iniconfig                             2.0.0
isodate                               0.6.1
isort                                 5.12.0
Jinja2                                2.10
lazy-object-proxy                     1.9.0
MarkupSafe                            2.0.0
mccabe                                0.7.0
msrest                                0.7.1
msrestazure                           0.6.4
oauthlib                              3.2.2
packaging                             23.1
pip                                   23.2.1
pipdeptree                            2.12.0
platformdirs                          3.9.1
pluggy                                1.2.0
protobuf                              3.6.1
ptvsd                                 4.3.2
py                                    1.11.0
pycparser                             2.21
PyJWT                                 2.8.0
pylint                                2.17.4
pytest                                7.4.0
pytest-cov                            4.1.0
python-dateutil                       2.8.2
python-dotenv                         1.0.0
python-http-client                    3.3.7
pytz                                  2023.3
requests                              2.31.0
requests-oauthlib                     1.3.1
retry                                 0.9.2
sendgrid                              6.10.0
setuptools                            58.1.0
six                                   1.12.0
starkbank-ecdsa                       2.2.0
tomli                                 2.0.1
tomlkit                               0.11.8
typed-ast                             1.5.5
typing_extensions                     4.7.1
urllib3                               2.0.4
```

I have tried to upgrade the azure-cosmos but still not working.
I have read the error.py is deprecated. Not really sure if that affects.

Thank you in advance for helping me solve this issue.

Comment: Can you share your init.py or app.py code if you are using v2 in your question?

Comment: Also, Try - pip install azure-cosmos==3.2.0 and run the function again?

Comment: Hi, im upgrading the function app v2 to v4 and i already upgraded the runtime and the version of the module, upon running there are error like that one. 

Now, I have fixed the issue by adding a script on the errors,py within the azure > cosmos lib/sitepackages then added from azure.cosmos.errors import HTTPFailure on in the init.py of the function.. The error was gone.. but once I have deployed it on the azure itself, and test run the function, it has '202 Accepted' output message but the still the function error upon checking the logs.

Comment: By what I understand, Azure Functions with Python only supports v1 and v2 models refer here- https://i.imgur.com/Z1dmr3s.png  - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-add-output-binding-cosmos-db-vs-code?tabs=in-process%2Cv1&pivots=programming-language-python Azure Functions Core tools contain version number 4.0 and in the host.json the function extension number is "extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
    "version": "[4.*, 5.0.0)" may I know which one are you referring to?

Comment: Because, If I create a default azure cosmos db trigger function with database and collections it is working and the extension bundle is set to "version": "[4.*, 5.0.0)"  in my host.json by default

Comment: Given my app.py for programming model v2 ifor cosmosdb trigger is like this- import azure.functions as func
import logging

app = func.FunctionApp()

@app.cosmos_db_trigger(arg_name="azcosmosdb", container_name="Items",
                        database_name="ToDoList", connection="siliconcosmosdb_DOCUMENTDB")  
def cosmosdb_trigger(azcosmosdb: func.DocumentList):
    logging.info('Python CosmosDB triggered.')

Comment: One way to resolve, Object serialized to String. Jarray instance expected is to serialize the json data properly - import json

data = {"key": "value"}
serialized_data = json.dumps(data)